# Symfony Twig variable not recognized (Variable does not exist)

Tags: php, database, symfony, controller, twig

This was working fine hours ago, I get data from database and simply display it in a table in Twig.
This is the controller from where I get the instance of the variable having my entity "Cours"

```
 /**
     * @Route("/listeCours", name="liste_cours")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $lstCours = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('App:Cours')
            ->findAll();

        return $this->render('liste_cours/index.html.twig', ['lstCours' => $lstCours]);
    }
```

I saved data from the repository for the entity "Cours" in the variable "lstCours" which is the one I will call later in twig here,

```
{% for cours in lstCours %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ cours.nom }}</td>
                            <td>{{ cours.type }}</td>
                            <td>{{ cours.description }}</td>
                            <td>{{ cours.prix }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn_apt btn"><a href="">Ajouter</a></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Compiler keep showing an exception saying the variable (lstCours) does not exist.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try to clear the cache

Comment: still the same exception

Comment: _"This was working fine hours ago"_ - what has changed inbetween? Can you backtrack any changes you've made to the code?

Comment: added redirections between interfaces, nothing that might interfere with that function. There is another one same as this one that works well but this one does not.

Comment: try dumping the file in twig. {{ dump(lstCours) }} and see what is in it.

Comment: tried it, still says it does not exist

Comment: If you add another dummy variable in the controller, can you access it in twig?

Comment: yes, the same function is used in another place for another entity and it works

Comment: the classic is a duplicate route or the template being included in a weird way.

Comment: try dumping $lstCours from your controller

Comment: it works whenever I change the route in the controller but only for one time then if I redirect to the same new route again the same exception shows up

Answer (score 0):

When you want to debug your Twig context, you can use:

```
{{ dump(_context) }}
```

It will show you all available variables in your template.